# Indexing stock price returns to 100 at start date

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset that contains daily percentage returns for different stock industries. The full dataset is too big to show here but here's a dummy dataframe with more or less the same structure:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['01/01/2020', 'energy', 0.25], ['01/02/2020', 'energy', -2], ['01/01/2020', 'technology', 1.5], ['01/02/2020', 'technology', 1], ['01/01/2020', 'healthcare', -1], ['01/02/2020', 'healthcare', 0.5]]),
                       columns=['date', 'industry', 'return'])
```

```
         date    industry return
0  01/01/2020      energy   0.25
1  01/02/2020      energy     -2
2  01/01/2020  technology    1.5
3  01/02/2020  technology      1
4  01/01/2020  healthcare     -1
5  01/02/2020  healthcare    0.5
```

I would like to make an index for each different industry that starts at 100 for the first date of the dataframe and then increases/decreases depending on the percentage return of that day until the final date in the dataframe. I can fill in the starting value of 100 for the earliest dates:

```
df['index'] = np.where(df['date'] == df['date'].min(), 100, 0)
```

```
         date    industry return  index
0  01/01/2020      energy   0.25    100
1  01/02/2020      energy     -2      0
2  01/01/2020  technology    1.5    100
3  01/02/2020  technology      1      0
4  01/01/2020  healthcare     -1    100
5  01/02/2020  healthcare    0.5      0
```

But I don't really know how to continue filling in the other index values from here. The output should look like this:

```
         date    industry return  index
0  01/01/2020      energy   0.25    100
1  01/02/2020      energy     -2     98
2  01/01/2020  technology    1.5    100
3  01/02/2020  technology      1    101
4  01/01/2020  healthcare     -1    100
5  01/02/2020  healthcare    0.5  100.5
```

Does anyone here know how to do this/can point me in the right direction?
* clarification: I need the 'compounding'  index value, not cumulative. For example, let's say I have 3 dates for an industry and the percentage returns are 0.5, 0.1, and 1.2 respectively, the index output should be 100 (starting date), 100.1 (100*1.001), and 101.3012 100(100.1*1.012)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) setting the first value of `return` for each industry with [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
#df['return']=df['return'].astype(float) #if necessary
df['index'] = (df['return'].mask(df['industry'].ne(df['industry'].shift()),0)
                           .groupby(df['industry'])
                           .cumsum().add(100))
print(df)
         date    industry  return  index
0  01/01/2020      energy    0.25  100.0
1  01/02/2020      energy   -2.00   98.0
2  01/01/2020  technology    1.50  100.0
3  01/02/2020  technology    1.00  101.0
4  01/01/2020  healthcare   -1.00  100.0
5  01/02/2020  healthcare    0.50  100.5
```

---

**UPDATED**

```
df['index'] =  (df['return'].astype(float)
                            .div(100)
                            .add(1)
                            .mask(df['industry'].ne(df['industry'].shift()),100)
                            .groupby(df['industry'])
                            .cumprod())
print(df)
         date    industry  return  index
0  01/01/2020      energy     0.5  100.0
1  01/02/2020      energy     0.1  100.1
2  01/01/2020  technology     1.2  100.0
3  01/02/2020  technology     0.5  100.5
4  01/01/2020  healthcare     0.1  100.0
5  01/02/2020  healthcare     1.2  101.2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using cumsum works for this example but I should have clarified better that I need the 'compounding'  value, not a cumulative value. It does not make a difference for this dummy dataframe because there are only 2 dates for each industry but let's say I have 3 dates for an industry and the percentage returns are 0.5, 0.1, and 1.2 respectively, the index output should be 100 (starting date), 100.1 (100*1.001), and 101.3012 100(100.1*1.012)